# simplifying bash code

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have following code in a shell script. It is all working fine.

```
#!/bin/bash

baseDirPath = '/stackoverflow/question'
newDir = '/stackoverflow/question/answers'


# first check some business condition
if [[ some condition here ]]
then
     # check if base Directory path already exit 
     if [ -d  $baseDirPath ];then

        # check if new Directory exits or not, if not create one 
        if [ ! -d $newDir ];then

          mkdir $newDir
          if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then
            echo "error occurred while creating directory "
          fi
        fi
     else
       exit 1;
     fi
fi
```

This is very confusing and not very clean code i feel.
I am very new to programming so not sure how it can be clean.

I am very curious if it can be made simpler or there is some other way to do this.

(The complete shell script is not shown above, just the complicated if-else  part is illustrated.)

Comment: Just a friendly FYI, shell scripts are not necessarily perl scripts. This particular shell script is bash, as indicated by the shebang (the `#!`) at the top. Perl is a separate programming language that looks similar to bash script but is much more powerful and full-featured.

Comment: As @mwp noted, this is not Perl.  I've modified the title to reflect that and made a few other edits to fix the code formatting and grammar. Feel free to [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33699153/edit) or rollback (and option on the edit page) if you don't like what I did.

Comment: Do you mean `baseDirPath='/stackoverflow/question'` without spaces? Assignments don't work if there is whitespace around the equal sign.

Comment: Also, run it all through http://shellcheck.net/ before asking here.

Comment: ...in general, though, StackOverflow questions about code require a **specific** problem or error, and a minimal reproducer that generates that problem. This doesn't qualify.

Comment: ...if code doesn't have a problem at all (as you claim this doesn't, though it won't actually work exactly as given), it isn't topical on StackOverflow -- that's what the Code Review SE is for.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Just to point out, if this was to be merged on CR, the whole code would be needed! :)

Comment: @PTBNL yes sorry perl should not have been mentioned.

Comment: @others : reason i am having this year as compared to Code Review SE because as mentioned in code snippet this is a very small part of actual code. This seems not very clean and scalable so overall integration with code will be issue. So i think it qualifies for Stack overflow only

Answer (score 4):

```
#!/bin/bash

die(){ >&2 printf '%s\n' "$@"; exit 1; }

#Can't have spaces here
baseDirPath='/stackoverflow/question' 
newDir='/stackoverflow/question/answers'


# first check some business condition
if [ some condition here ]; then
     # check if base Directory path already exit 
   mkdir -p "$newDir" ||  die 'error occured while creating directory'
fi
```

This changes the semantics slightly--it exits if the creation of `newDirs` fails for whatever reasons -- `baseDirPath` is not a directory or `baseDirPath` is a directory and `newDir` cannot be created.

You can probably get rid of that error message too. `mkdir` will already give you an error on stderr if it fails for some reason:

```
mkdir -p "$newDir" || exit 1
```

If most of your commands should work like this (i.e., either succeed or bring down the whole script), then you're probably better off setting `set -e` (~ exit when a command returns with a nonzero status) and then just doing:

```
mkdir -p "$newDir"
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be pretty thoroughly simplified:

```
#!/bin/bash
baseDirPath='/stackoverflow/question'
newDir='/stackoverflow/question/answers'

# first check some business condition
if [[ some condition here ]]; then
    if ! mkdir -p "${newDir}"; then
        echo "Unable to create directory ${newDir}.  Aborting."
        exit 1
    fi
    # Proceed as normal
fi
```

If you really do need for the `baseDirPath` to exist, then that can certainly be added as a condition:

```
if [[ ! -d "${baseDirPath}" ]] || ! mkdir -p "${newDir}"; then
```

Comment: Why the curly braces? None of these expansions are being parameterized, and there's no disambiguating the variable name either in any of these cases.

Comment: I habitually use curly braces at all times as a means to disambiguate variable names; it also means I don't have to thing when embedding a variable into other text (e. g. `${varname}_ext` which is semantically distinct from `$varname_ext`).  Since using curls at all times is the rule rater than the exception, it makes more consistent syntax.  That's also the reason I always use `[[ ]]` pairs even though `[ ]` will technically work.